# twilio php curl not returning carrier

Tags: php, curl

My TWILIO curl query doesnt seem to return anything but country code and phone numbers any ideas?

When I lookup on twilio the carrier comes thru fine
Results from my test page were:

```
no curl error

stdClass Object
(
    [caller_name] => 
    [country_code] => US
    [phone_number] => +1201832xxxx
    [national_format] => (201) 832-xxxx
    [carrier] => 
    [add_ons] => 
    [url] => https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+1201832xxxx
)

caller_name is 
caller_name is 
caller_type is 
error_code is 
country_code is US
phone number is +1201832xxxx
national_format (201) 832-xxxx
Carrier name is 
Carrier name is 
Carrier type is 
error_code is 
mobile_network_code 
mobile_country_code is 
no curl error
```

The code is below

```
 $cSession =     curl_init("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+1201832xxxx");

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Type=carrier");

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx");


$response           =       curl_exec($cSession);

$err = curl_error($cSession);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err."<br/>";
} else {
echo "no curl error<br/>";  

}

$response           =       json_decode($response);

echo "<pre>";   print_r($response); echo "</pre><br/>";
echo "caller_name is ".$response->caller_name."<br/>"; 
echo "caller_name is ".$response->caller_name->caller_name."<br/>";
echo "caller_type is ".$response->caller_name->caller_type."<br/>";
echo "error_code is ".$response->caller_name->error_code."<br/>";
echo "country_code is ".$response->country_code."<br/>";    
echo "phone number is ".$response->phone_number."<br/>";

echo "national_format ".$response->national_format."<br/>";
echo "Carrier name is ".$response->carrier."<br/>";
echo "Carrier name is ".$response->carrier->name."<br/>";
echo "Carrier type is ".$response->carrier->type."<br/>";  
echo "error_code is ".$response->carrier->error_code."<br/>";
echo "mobile_network_code ".$response->carrier->mobile_network_code."<br/>";
echo "mobile_country_code is ".$response->carrier->mobile_country_code."<br/>";
```

Comment: `if ($err)` isn't a valid test. if the site you're scraping naturally returns an empty string or a `0` character, that'll also count as false and trigger a false-positive. You have to explicitly test for boolean false, `if ($err === false)` instead. it is not possible for a website to return a php boolean false. it can only return TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

I used shell_exec instead using the [xget command posted on twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/lookups) and I got the responses i needed

```
$cmd="curl -XGET 'https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+1201832xxxx?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name' -u 'clientidxxxxxx:clienttokenxxxxxx' ";
$result=shell_exec($cmd);

$response           =       json_decode($result);

echo "<pre>";   print_r($response); echo "</pre><br/>";
```

Comment: This is not the way to do this. Twilio provides a great library to work with their data. Why aren't you using the library that is referenced on the link you posted?